# MySql: How to show India first and rest of the country ascending order using mysql query?

Tags: mysql

Suppose the table have 1 column only and have values Canada, London, India, Australia. Now using MYSQL query how to display India 1st and rest of the name after India by ascending order?

Comment: See FIELD(). And note that there is a manual for this stuff.

Comment: What did you try? How did your attempt differ from your expected result m Please visit the SO Help Section, linked to at the top of every page, for guidelines on how to as a question. Questions that do not meet SO requirements are subject to deleting from the platform. Remember, this is not a "free coding service", but s platform of volunteers who help each other wish specific coding issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select name from country order by name='India' desc, name;
```

I think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

create table #temp
(
country nvarchar(25)
)

insert into #temp
values ('Canada'), ('London'), ('India'), ('Australia')

select * from #temp
order by case when country='India' then 1 else 2 end

drop table #temp

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from 'table_name' order by (case when name='India' then 0 else 1 end), name asc
```

If you want to show any **two or more countries** first then

> (case when name='India' then 0 else 1 end)

**will be**

> (case when name='first_country_name' then 0 when name='second_country_name' then 1 else 2 end)

Here you can use negative value as condition.